# Regex match Telegram username and delete whole line in PHP

Tags: php, regex, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I wanna match Telegram username in message text and delete entire line, I've tried this pattern but the problem is that it matches emails too:

`.*(@(?=.{5,64}(?:\s|$))(?![_])(?!.*[_]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?<![_.])).*`

*Pattern should match all this lines :*

Hi @username how are you?

Hi @username.how are you?

@username.

*And should not match email like this:*

Hi email to something@domain.com

Comment: It may have more than one emoji before @

Comment: I was thinking `.*[^a-zA-Z]@` ... which would be far from perfect. Then I looked up http://emailregex.com/ And thought... maybe that would be helpful? You could maybe get your match as you have it, then use another regex to check if the "username" is actually a username, or if it's an email.

Comment: Is it about emojis only? Or non word characters? Can the @ occur more than once in the string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
.*\B@(?=\w{5,32}\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*.*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/J97QQu/6)

`\B` before `@` means there must be a non-word character or start of string right before the `@`.

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \B                       the boundary between two word chars (\w)
                           or two non-word chars (\W)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w{5,32}                 word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
                             (between 5 and 32 times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9' (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 1):

`.*[\W](@(?=.{5,64}(?:\s|$))(?![_])(?!.*[_]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?<![_.])).*`

I've added this `[\W]` non-word characters before @ symbol.
Here you can check the result https://regex101.com/r/yFGegO/1

Answer (score 1):

Nothing new under the sun, but basically other patterns can be reduced to:

```
.*?\B@\w{5}.*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mAyMtW/1)

or eventually:

```
.*?\B\w{5,64}\b.*
```

if you want to be more precise, but is it really needed?

Notice: if you want to remove the newline sequence too, add `\R?` at the end of the pattern.